# QML TableView with delegated Checkbox has problems to show the

Tags: qt, checkbox, delegates, qml, tableview

I created a dummy `ListModel` and loaded it to the `TableView`:

```
ListModel {
    id: testModel

    ListElement {
        status: false
    }
}    

function testFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
        testModel.append({});
    }
}

TableView {  
    model: testModel

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "status"
        title: "Activation On/Off" 
        delegate: Checkbox {
            id: idDelegatedCheckbox
        }           
    }        
}
```

I pretend to use the `Checkbox` as delegate component to select the items in the `TableView`. I check the first item in the table in the following way:

First item selected

[image]

Then I scroll down and return to the top and the items that I had selected disappear and other item is selected:

Different item selected

[image]

Do you know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I think it is, citing the documentation, that **"For performance reasons, created delegates can be recycled across multiple table rows. This implies that when you make use of implicit properties such as styleData.row or model, these values can change after the delegate has been constructed."**

Answer (score 5):

TableView delegates are instantiated as needed and may be recycled or destroyed at any time. As with any Qt Quick item views (`ListView`, `GridView`, `PathView`, `TableView`...), state should never be stored in a delegate. Hence, your `CheckBox` delegate must store its "checked" state in the model:

```
delegate: Checkbox {
    id: idDelegatedCheckbox
    checked: model.checked // read from the model when created or recycled
    onCheckedChanged: model.checked = checked // write to the model when checked or unchecked
}
```

Comment: this is really sweet, it also works with C++ models, where checked would be some roleName